# Where do I find data sent with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I try to work with Google Tag Manager in Magento, but i can't find where data sent with dataLayer[] is dysplayed in Google Analytics.My events are fired and registred in  Google Analytics.Can someone tell me where I find the data from dataLayer[]?

Comment: Unless you have specifically set the data from dataLayer as custom dimensions in your Analytics tags it won't be send to Analytics. Can you share your configuration so we can make suggestions on how to improve your setup ?

Answer (score 1):

Think of `dataLayer` as a common storage medium between your website and Google Tag Manager. Pushing objects onto the array does not mean they are automatically added to Google Analytics. You need to configure Tags, Macros and Firing Rules in GTM to connect them.

To collect data with Google Analytics, usually one would create two Tags for GA. One for page views and the other for event tracking.

The page view tag would have a firing rule which runs on all pages and behaves like the Google Analytics snippet that we used to paste into the page html. Using GTM just means it can run async and without modifying the html of the page (other than adding the GTM snippet).

The event tracking tag would listen for objects in the data array with `event="GAEvent"` and when present, sends them to Google Analytics as an Event.

Both support custom dimensions, so you can add additional values to the objects pushed to the `dataLayer`. To make them work, you would need to create a Macro which looks for a Data Layer Variable, then in your GA Tag you would output the macro like so: `{{yourMacroName}}`.

To see what is inside the dataLayer array, on any page, open your browser dev console and type `console.log(dataLayer)` or just `dataLayer`.